# bind asp.net gridview column form textbox value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind gridview column from textbox value for example: I have two textbox and a button what i exactly want that i will give input in the two textboxes and when i clicked the button the textbox values will  show in gridviw and want to do this for  multiple times without replacing the previous values.

I found so many relevant answer but all are done with hard code inside  button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Name",  
    typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Age", typeof(decimal)) });
    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind()
}
```

which replace the previous values when i insert new values, but i want to keep all the previous values in which I stuck  .thanks

Comment: this is because you create new datatable . what you need to to first get the data  from datagrid convert to table and then append new rows .

Comment: if you want I can spend some time to write the code . Please let me know

Comment: Hi I tried to write the code please try . If it helps please mark it as answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the values from each `PostBack` into a Session or `ViewState`, otherwise you'll lose all the data when the button is clicked again.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt;

    //check if the datatable already exists in the viewstate, if not create a new datatable
    if (ViewState["myTable"] == null)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Age", typeof(decimal)) });
    }
    else
    {
        //correct viewstate exists, cast back to a datatable
        dt = ViewState["myTable"] as DataTable;
    }

    //add the new values
    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox2.Text));

    //bind the datatable to the gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    //save the datatable into the viewstate
    ViewState["myTable"] = dt;

    //clear the textboxes
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you to get current data from gridview to datatable 
and then you can append new rows accordingly .

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DataTable dt =GetGridData();
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }

  private DataTable GetGridData ()
  {
   DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
   for (int i = 0; i < grdReport.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
    _datatable.Columns.Add(grdReport.Columns[i].ToString());
   }
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdReport.Rows)
{
    DataRow dr = _datatable.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < grdReport.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (!row.Cells[j].Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
            dr[grdReport.Columns[j].ToString()] = row.Cells[j].Text;
    }

    _datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
  }
return _dataTable;
}
```